# Symfony / Api-platform updates rehash password on put request gives error when login in again

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have an issue when I update a field firstname or lastname for exemple the hashed password is rehashed and changed in my database. So when I login I have an error even if the field password is not in the PUT request. How is it possible ? Thanks

I have a basic user entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: "email", message: "L'email est déjà utilisé")]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:write']],
    collectionOperations: [
        "get" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"],
        "post"=> ["security" => ["is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"], ],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        "get",
        "put" => ["security" => "object == user"],
        "delete" => ["security" => "object == user"],
    ],
)]


class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email(
        message: "L'email '{{ value }}' n'est pas un email valide.",
    )]
    #[Groups(["user:read", "user:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    private $email;
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private $roles = [];

    #[Groups("user:write")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private $password;

    #[Groups(["user:read", "user:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $firstname;

    #[Groups(["user:read", "user:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $lastname;

    #[Groups(["user:read", "user:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $photo;

    #[Groups(["user:read", "user:write"])]
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Favorite::class, mappedBy: 'userId')]
    private $favorites;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->favorites = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
.... 
}
```

And have a data persister to encode the password

```
<?php

namespace App\DataPersister;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class UserDataPersister implements DataPersisterInterface
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $userPasswordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->userPasswordEncoder = $userPasswordHasherInterface;
    }

    public function supports($data): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof User;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $data
     */
    public function persist($data)
    {
        if ($data->getPassword()) {
            $data->setPassword(
                $this->userPasswordEncoder->hashPassword($data, $data->getPassword())
            );
            $data->eraseCredentials();
        }

        $this->entityManager->persist($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    public function remove($data)
    {
        $this->entityManager->remove($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I don't see any getter and setter for the firstname and lastname in your entity. And I also don't see an updateUser method in your repository.

Comment: Try to use encodePassword method insead of hashpasswod.

Comment: encodePassword  is deprecated with the version of Symfony that i use. https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-passwordhasher-component

Comment: @Monnomcjo i have deleted them for the purpose of the post but they existe

Comment: What method are you calling to update your user? and can you show it to us?

Comment: My bad I didn't follow the documentation quite thoroughly. It's not an issue anymore